# CMU Sphinx 4-5prealpha : "WARNING: Grammar missing self identifying header"

Tags: java, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I'm trying to get used to CMU sphinx 4-5prealpha. 
Everything works fine with recognition without grammar, but I need to handle not really much commands / words / phrases. So, here goes some code and error stack :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();


    configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
    configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
    configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");
    configuration.setGrammarPath("/home/enchanting/records");
    configuration.setGrammarName("hello");
    configuration.setUseGrammar(true);


    LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
```

// Start recognition process pruning previously cached data.

```
    while(true){
        recognizer.startRecognition(true);
        System.out.println("go!");
        String utterance = recognizer.getResult().getHypothesis();
        System.out.println(utterance);
        recognizer.stopRecognition();
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

So, I am TOTALLY sure that my location of grammar file is ok, and the mistake is:

```
> WARNING: Grammar missing self identifying header
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Allocation of search manager resources failed
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.JSGFGrammarParseException
```

UPDATE:
My bad, forgot to paste my grammar :D

```
> hello.gram
#JSGF V1.0;
grammar hello;
public <intro> = "Computer";
```

Comment: If your grammar file isn't that big, it might make sense to post it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it wasn't a sphinx bug or something - just my innatention. I was editing another grammar file "grammar.gram" instead of "hello.gram". Mistakes were done, now it works fine!